Kivy's Label goes Blank after handling too much data
I'm new to both Kivy and Python and we have a Label that is exceeding texture size in ScrollView when a new flow of data is fed to it upon scan triggered by a Button. Let's say in the Pixel 7 emulator, when texture size of Label on y axis exceeds hardware's texture size limit: 8192 that Label goes blank/black but it is still possible to scroll through but nothing is visible apart from the top information e.g., Buttons or other Widgets.
I've been looking through the internet hoping to find an answer however, it is a pointless search. Some users refer to RecycleView but Kivy documentation does not make it easy implementing it and from my understanding RV is designed to handle bigger influx of data and is more memory efficient. Question is, does RV also help with texture size limitations?
I came across an article (cannot find link to it) which led me reading up on ScrollLabel but the repository on Git seems dead.

If you exceed the max texture size in an Image, you can create a series of smaller Images, and just display them consecutively in a ScrollView. See this question. Might be able to do something similar with Labels.

Thank you for your comment @John Anderson. I'm not sure how to begin creating smaller series of Label. Our Label has it's text attribute "updated" every time a scan is carried out. That scan is to scan nearby networks which happen every ~5 seconds after button is pushed. Would Label behave as Image inside the Pillow or opencv? Our App architecture goes like this: Window > Bottom > ScrollView > Label. I'm sorry I know this is a very brief description but this made me bang my head against the wall for few days now and I feel like I'm confusing myself with it all.

I also have been testing TextInputs as read-only but it seems slow but doesn't seem to go blank/black but ScrollView behaves funny with it. We're trying threading to speed things up.

I attempted RecycleView, but my understanding of it is limited. I have self.recycle_view = RecycleView() instanisated, its viewclass has assigned label. However, when I try to print to output data onto the screen it will not work. I have self.recycle_view.data = [{'text' : "Test"}] apart from the console nothing is printed but it is populated.

If you use a TextInput, you probably don't need a ScrollView, since a TextInput does its own scrolling.

By the way, if you are just processing text, you can do all your separating into smaller Labels by using pythons string methods to split the text into smaller pieces before creating any Labels.

We have adapted our app to work with RecycleView. It is not a begineer friendly way of implementing scrolling in your app but is better than ScrollView if you're handling lots of data information. To my understanding, it doesn't worry so much about exceeding texture_size as above but lazy-loads and recycles your widgets. I'm surprised how ScrollView hasn't been deprecated yet, but after writing RV's... Kivy needs to find an easier way of implementing them otherwise it's a hassle.
I would recommend closely studying the docs on Kivy, removing and adding stuff as you seem to fit to see how everything functions. To my knowledge, it is much easier to use Kivy's builder from kivy.lang.builder to define your RV (RecycleView) in .kv lang and it's widgets. Use Kivy's Properties as it makes everything easier to reference. Make sure how Classes work in Python! At least, understand the basics. Even I until today don't know what super() does.
Links that helped us:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#keyword-arguments-and-init

And many, many, many StackOverflow posts...
